# Selenium Python script on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, bash, selenium-webdriver, deployment, pythonanywhere

I can't run my selenium python script on the website pythonanywhere, I recieve error for this line:

```
line 31, in createDriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=chrome_service)
```

I installed the following requirements:

```
selenium
webdriver-manager
chromedriver-binary
python-dotenv
timeunit
```

and the problem persists.

This what I get when running:
[image: Error screenshot]

I tried to run these commands:

```bash
pip3.7 install --user selenium==4.1.3
mkvirtualenv myproject
workon myproject
pip install selenium
```

Here is my function:

[image: Code screenshot]

Comment: Please do not post error messages and your code as screenshots. You can [edit] your question to include them in user-friendly manner (as text, wrapped in code blocks)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use ChromeDriverManager on PythonAnywhere. The correct chromedriver is already installed and available. If you use ChromeDriverManager, it is likely that you would end up using the wrong chromedriver.